# django-rest-framework: Why my API returns key instead value for my ENUMS?

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework

I got stuck in my first API development. I hope someone can tell me what I do wrong.

here is my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

COUNTRY_LIST = [('PL', 'Poland'), ('DK', 'Denmark'), ('FI', 'Finland')]


class Trip(models.Model):

    startDate = models.DateField()
    endDate = models.DateField()
    country = models.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRY_LIST, max_length=2)
```

here is my **serializers.py**:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from trips.models import Trip, COUNTRY_LIST, CLIENTS_LIST, TRANSPORTS_LIST, STATUS_LIST

# Trip Serializer


class TripSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = '__all__'
```

here is my **api_views.py**:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, CreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
from trips.serializers import TripSerializer
from trips.models import Trip
import re

class TripList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Trip.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TripSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'tripStatus', 'employeeId')
    search_fields = ('place', 'remarks')
```

here is my **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

import trips.views
import trips.api_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('trip', trips.api_views.TripList.as_view()),
```

The Issue description:
Currently with the design as abowe my API responds with data where key of my enum is returned like so:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "startDate": "2019-11-04",
    "endDate": "2019-11-05",
    "country": "PL"
},
```

I suppose that I need to implement some changes in serializers.py to make it respond like that:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "startDate": "2019-11-04",
    "endDate": "2019-11-05",
    "country": "Poland"
},
```

Can someone can give me some advice here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [django-rest-framework-3.6.3](/questions/tagged/django-rest-framework-3.6.3), you can specify the `source=...` parameter and specify that it should use the display of that value:

```
class TripSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = serializers.CharField(source='get_country_display')

    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = '__all__'
```

So here instead of using the `country` value itself, we use the `get_country_display`.

Comment: Generally it works perfectly when reading the data from API. But now it seems that my POST (Trip creation) stopped working. When I send POST I got following error from my API.    TypeError at /trip/new
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Trip.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Trip.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the TripSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.